# php registration mysql not a valid resource

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

Ok help..my registration page worked on the local server but its now saying that the two mysql lines are not valid when its online..why does it change when it goes online? the code pasted is all thats relevant. for some reason it doesnt like the transaction..and the email check mysql bit

```
include 'Connect.php'; //Connects to database
//When form is submit:-
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{         
                        // On submit, retrieve table values for php.                 
                        $Firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
                        $Surname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['surname']);
                        $Password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); 
                        $PasswordCheck = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passwordcheck']); 
                        $Email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']); 
                        $EmailCheck = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emailcheck']); 

                    //CHECKS. 
                    //Check username is available by retrieving any same values from the DB table.          
                    $CheckEmailAvailable = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'user_details' WHERE Email = '$Email'");
                    echo $CheckEmailAvailable;
                    // $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl WHERE Email='$email' and LoginPassword='$password'");
                    $Results = mysql_fetch_array($CheckEmailAvailable);

                    //If Username field is blank.
                    if($Email == null )
                    {               
                        echo "You must enter an email address.";
                        $url = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
                        echo "<br/><br/>";
                        echo "<a href='$url'>Click Here To Return</a>";
                        die();                      
                    }

                    //If RESULTS is any value other than NULL, die.
                    if($Results != null )
                    {               
                        echo "Email already taken. Please try another.";
                        $url = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
                        echo "<br/><br/>";
                        echo "<a href='$url'>Click Here To Return</a>";
                        die();                  
                    }

                    //If Password and PasswordCheck fields in reg do not match, die.
                    if($Password != $PasswordCheck) 
                    {
                        echo "The passwords you have entered do not match. Please try again.";
                        $url = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
                        echo "<br/><br/>";
                        echo "<a href='$url'>Click Here To Return</a>";
                        die();
                    }

                    //If Password field is NULL (i.e. blank) die.
                    if($Password == Null)
                    {
                        echo "Your password must not be blank.";
                        $url = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
                        echo "<br/><br/>";
                        echo "<a href='$url'>Click Here To Return</a>";
                        die();
                    }

                    //If Email and EmailCheck are not equal, die.
                    if($Email != $EmailCheck)
                    {                                                                        
                        echo "The email addresses you have entered do not match. Please try again.";
                        $url = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
                        echo "<br/><br/>";
                        echo "<a href='$url'>Click Here To Return</a>";
                        die();

                    }


                    //ELSE add data to DB.
                    else
                    {
                    //BEGIN TRANS
                    mysql_query("BEGIN TRAN");

                    //TABLE ADD.
                    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user_details` (`Firstname`, `Surname`, `Email`, `Password`) VALUES ('$Firstname', '$Surname', '$Email', '$Password')")
                    or mysql_query("ROLLBACK TRAN") . die(mysql_error("Error registering, the database may be down, please try again later."));


                    //COMMIT transaction, to ensure data is added properly.
                    mysql_query("COMMIT TRAN");
                    header( 'Location: RegSucc.php' ) ;
                    }   
                } ?>
              <html> 
            <!--Registration Form-->
            <form name="form1" method="post" style="margin-left: 28%" action="Register.php">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><strong>Register Account</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 83px">First Name:</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><input name="firstname" type="text"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 83px">Surname:</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><input name="surname" type="text"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 83px">Email Address:</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><input name="email" type="text"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 83px">Email Address Confirmation:</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><input name="emailcheck" type="text"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 83px">Password:</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><input name="password" type="password"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 83px">Verify Password:</td>
                    <td>:</td>
                    <td><input name="passwordcheck" type="password"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 83px">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"/></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

Comment: Compare your local and online database versions.  Also check the table types of both (MyISAM vs InnoDB). Verify they match.

Comment: You're probably missing a field or table in the online database. Use `mysql_error()` to see a description of the problem.

Comment: Are You using InnoDB or MyIsam on the server (not local machine)? Probably You use MyIsam that do not support transactions...

Comment: Yeah so turns out the default for the online database is MyIsam, so when i imported the InnoDB tables there's now a confilict..not sure how to change the default database type (dont think there is a way on this server) so im going to have to take out the transaction :/ Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user_details` (`Firstname`, `Surname`, `Email`, `Password`) VALUES ('$Firstname', '$Surname', '$Email', '$Password')")
```

should be

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_details (Firstname, Surname, Email, Password) VALUES ('$Firstname', '$Surname', '$Email', '$Password')")
```

Also

```
SELECT * FROM 'user_details' WHERE Email = '$Email'
```

should be

```
SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE Email = '$Email'
```

that's it...

Comment: How did You get to this one? Why to take off all the backticks? -1 cos this answer will not solve anything...

Comment: Thanks, this contributed to fixing it!

Comment: @shadyyx : OP problem is solved, do you have anything to say??

Comment: -1 removed due to the edit. First one is still unconstructive... But I think @ConnorPeet 's answer should be accepted as he answered this right as first...

Answer (score 1):

The query

```
SELECT * FROM 'user_details' WHERE Email = '$Email'
```

Is invalid. When denoting table names, it is good practice to use backticks, but using quotes will not work!

```
SELECT * FROM `user_details` WHERE Email = '$Email'
```

On your localhost, it may be setup to work with quotes. However, that is not the way it is "supposed" to be, and the server's installation may be different. Moral of the story: don't take shortcuts or use ugly code. Don't forget to backtick table names or columns, don't use PHP shorttags, etc.

Comment: even if you don't use backticks, it will work. backticks are needed in pgAdmin only...

Comment: @FahimParkar, in one website job I was befuddled as to why all my simple queries weren't working. Apparently, there is a MySQL compile option to require backticks. Since including backticks doesn't hurt and only serves to make the website more compatible, I got into the habit of including them.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
$CheckEmailAvailable = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'user_details' WHERE Email = '$Email'");
```

to

```
$CheckEmailAvailable = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE Email = '".$Email."'");
```

The problem is that when you moved to another server online (I can guess you were developing on Windows[which is case insensitive in MySQL], and your online server is Linux[case sensitive in MySQL]

If your string contains a variable to be evaluated and parsed, the use of single quotes around that variable name, within the double quote containing that string, is not so reliable most times. The best approach, (from personal experiences) is to do a concatenation.